# Binding a ListBox to an ObservableCollection in XAML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, binding

I have a ListBox and a sample ObservableCollection, when I set listBox1.ItemsSource = _collection; in code-behind file, it works fine, but when I do like this in XAML:

```
   ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}"
```

It doesn't work. In what could be the problem?

In code-behind I have

```
public ObservableCollection<FeedItem> Collection
{
    get { return _collection; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mostly likely the DataContext of the ListBox (or any of its parents) is not set.
Bind the DataContext to the object holding the collection, and you should be good to go.

Comment: Yes, u are right. When I do `this.DataContext = _collection` and in .xaml `ItemSource = {Binding}` all works fine.Thx